# What is a good way to see errors thrown in production with Swift and no third party frameworks?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I have an app that uses WatchConnectivity to send information from an iPhone app to an Apple Watch app. In some cases, I'm using `updateApplicationContext(_:)`, which throws. This isn't very relevant to the question, but I'm mentioning it so I can provide a code example below.

**I'm interested in finding out reasons why this is failing in production, so that I can handle errors in the future.** More generally, I want to improve my error handling throughout any apps I build, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to find out which errors are being thrown in different scenarios in production so I can address those.

Obviously, it is a bad idea to ship an app with `fatalError` in it, but I thought maybe that would at least be a way I can get this data to show up with crashes in Xcode using this code:

```
do {
       try WCSession.default.updateApplicationContext(phoneInfo)
   } catch(let error) {
       // This actually does fail in the wild... I'd like to know the reason or reasons
       fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
   }
```

However, I know from other more severe cases experimenting with `fatalError` in production when I was a newer developer that I don't actually get the `localizedDescription` with the crash in the Xcode crash logs. I'm assuming this only writes the `localizedDescription` out to the console, but not to crash logs.

**What is a good way that I can get information about errors that are thrown in production?** I'd like to avoid using third party frameworks.

Comment: I don't understand why this would be downvoted. It's a valid concern.

Comment: I try to avoid third-party frameworks as much as anybody but I don't understand why you'd want to avoid them here. Google's Firebase Crashlytics, for example, has a very generous free tier and is incredibly performant. That said, do you use a 3PF for remote databasing or is that custom-built as well? If your app connects to a remote database, however it does, just record errors in there—that's all that a framework like Crashlytics really does, anyway. If your app doesn't use a remote database, then just email yourself errors using Apple's `MessageUI` framework.

Comment: @bsod With Firebase, for example, how would you recommend I use it to accomplish what I’m looking to achieve? Send an event every time there’s an error?

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics automatically logs crash events (exception errors, fatal errors—whatever would cause the program itself to terminate) in a web-based GUI for you to monitor (and filter, search, etc.). You can install it using Cocoapods and have it running in minutes. You can also configure it to log dSYM files from the client as well which may help you perform stack traces, for example. I can't imagine there is a widely-used production app in the world that doesn't use something like this for error logging.

Comment: @bsod In this specific case, I’m not looking to actually crash the app, I just was thinking that may be one way I could get the error into Xcode so I could see what it is. How would you recommend I report back this error without a crash? Is firing an event in Firebase a good practice for doing that? Or is there some other mechanism it provides for this kind of logging?

Comment: Crashlytics logs crash events, it doesn't create them, so it's a good idea to use it no matter what you decide to do. But if you want to log errors that don't crash the app, then what I'd suggest you do is set up a remote database, like Firestore (also with a generous free tier), and write to it whenever a non-fatal error occurs. I don't think there is a better way to log errors than in a database.